# what does " void (*f)(void) " in C mean

Tags: c

Can anyone explain this line of code in C :

```
void (*f)(void)= &fs ;
```

I tried to look in google for an explanation but i didn't find anything about it.

Comment: Learn about function pointers.

Comment: it's a function pointer.

Comment: Specifically, a pointer to a function taking no parameters and returning nothing. Now that you know that it's a function pointer, that should help refine your Google search.

Comment: For a pointer to a function, `void (*f)(void) = &fs;` is the same as `void (*f)(void) = fs;`

Answer (score 3):

It is defining a variable 'f' that is a function pointer which points to the function 'fs'. 'fs' is a function that takes no arguments are returns nothing so it might look like:

```
void fs(void) { printf("in fs"); }
```

If you ran the following code after the line in your question

```
(*f)();
```

It would call 'fs' and you would get a print out of "in fs"

Comment: We don't know that `fs` is such a function. We just know that it should be that.

Comment: True klutt - C will compile anything you provide when it comes to pointers and so it is up to the programmer to make sure that the function signatures are the same (or similar enough). Ideally 'f' and 'fs' would have the same signature otherwise the behaviour becomes quite environment specific.

Answer (score 2):

I put the same statement in **[cdecl](https://cdecl.org/?q=void+%28*f%29%28void%29)** and its shows me

> *declare `f` as pointer to function `(void)` returning `void`*.

That is it!! In other words, here, we define a variable `f` of type as a pointer-to-a-function which accepts no arguments, (`(void)`) and returns a `void`, too. We are initializing the variable with the address of another function `fs`, so that, `f` points to the `fs` function and can be used to call / invoke `fs`.